# Django form modelmultiplechoicefield

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I filtered and listed matches but when I try to select and add matches, the matches I have selected are not added.

views.py

```
def creategame(request,tournamentslug):


    form=GameForm(request.POST or None)
    tournament = get_object_or_404(Tournament, slug=tournamentslug)

     form.fields["match"]=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'matchc'}),required=False,queryset=Match.objects.filter(name__icontains=tournament.name))

if form.is_valid():
    game = form.save(commit=False)
    #game have more than 1 fields such name,date.. and more
    """
    fields=['name',
            'date',...
            ]
    """
    game.tournament=tournament
    game.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(game.get_absolute_url())
```

html

```
              <div class="form-item">
                <label for="id_match" class="rl-label" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Match:</label>
                  {{ form.match }}
              </div>
```

Comment: Where do you save your form?

Comment: @DanielHolmes i added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added under the `game.save()` below code and it works

```
form.save_m2m()
```